# Lost history in github desktop for a repo and getting 'Failed to Sync branch' error - how do I resync?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I've used Github exclusively through the Github Desktop UI on Win 7, happily been syncing with online copy on github.com for a while but then accidentally deleted my local .git folder in the repo, so GitHub Desktop no longer shows the many previous commits, although they're all there online.

I've since made changes to various files in the local repo. I re-entered the correct remote address in Github Desktop, which now shows a 'Publish' button rather than the usual 'Sync' but clicking this just brings up a 'Failed to sync branch' error.

How do I sort this mess out? Basically just want things back the way they were with repo history showing in Github Desktop (ideally) or at least my latest changes to local files correctly synced online. I don't really want to have to create a whole new repo and publish to that and lose the existing history.

I'm not familiar with git shell or command line but can use if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new local clone of the online repo somewhere else, e.g. `local2`, go into that directory, and copy the `.git` directory to your original local repo. You'd still lose whatever local config and branches you have created before - those would be in the `.git` you deleted, but at least you'll be able to commit and push your local changes.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry - newbie question, how do I make a new local clone of the online repo?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the GUI tool you are using, but essentially just the same procedure you followed when you created and sync'ed your existing local repo the first time.